# Is there any way to "help" a mobile device OS to detect a code from an SMS?

Tags: android, ios, sms

I have an SMS sender service that sends an OTP to mobile devices.
The OTP message is very simple and is plain text:

> Here's your OTP 123456, paste it in the OTP section of the website

On IOS I have that the system is smart enough to detect there is an OTP: by tapping on the SMS I get a dialog saying "COPY CODE" , sweet!

On Android it doesn't happen: it detects there is a code because I see it in blue, like an hyperlink text, but when I tap on it the calling dialog pops out.

I'm not very expert about the SMS syntax, maybe is there a way to forge an SMS with some "hint" that could help the most of mobile devices to detect there is a code in the SMS and achieve the same behavior of IOS?

Comment: Probably set on an android (or coded in SW) that number in text can be callable.
Perhaps you can try to put number in quotes (e.g. "123456")

Comment: If your app has to read that code then this should be used: https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview

Comment: It's not an app, it's a plain website :(